# ASP.NET Mobile App getting "500 Internal Sever Error" from requesting a simple GET action

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-api-apps

I created an ASP.NET Web Application - Azure Mobile App project in Visual Studio. I haven't modified  anything, so it has the default todo item controller. If I run the program locally and use a REST client to request a GET action from

> localhost:port/tables/TodoItem

with the header **ZUMO-API-VERSION** set at **2.0.0** everything works perfectly. I published the app to Azure and when I try to request a GET action from

> MYLINK.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem

with the header **ZUMO-API-VERSION** set at **2.0.0** I get (after about 1 minute) a "500 Internal Sever Error" with the message "An error has occurred." If I don't add the header I get almost instantly the "400 Bad Request" saying that I have to specify the API version. Am I doing something wrong? What causes this problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was happening because the default project that Azure creates for the back-end is intended to be used with SQL. You could leverage [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) or [Azure App Service Editor](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36467.understanding-the-azure-app-service-editor.aspx) to check your `MS_TableConnectionString` connectionstring under your web.config file. The connectionstring would look like this:

`<add name="MS_TableConnectionString" connectionString="Server=tcp:{your_dbservername}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={your_dbname};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

When deploy your mobile app to Azure via Visual Studio, you need to point your connectionstring to your Azure db as follows:

[image]

For more details about creating and deploying your mobile app to Azure App Service, you could refer to this [document](https://github.com/Microsoft/HealthClinic.biz/wiki/Create-and-deploy-a-mobile-app-in-Azure-App-Service). Also, you could leverage "All Settings > Application settings" under your web app blade to configure your connectionstring, which could override your existing connectionstring in your web.config file at runtime. For more details, you could follow this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure).

After configuring that, you will work well.
[image]
Additionally, you could follow [Adrian Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1313441/adrian-hall)'s book [here](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/) for a better understanding and a quick start with Azure Mobile Apps.